# Using a plot call in a function without evaluating it

Tags: r, function, plot, r-markdown

In a Rmarkdown document, I want to accellerate the knitting process by only building the plots when they have not been already built and saved.

I did this using the code below, with a simple example.

```
x = rnorm(10)
if (! "figurename" %in% dir("figure")) {
    png("figure/figurename.png")
    hist(x)
    dev.off()
}
```

Now I want to make a function, that does the above command automatically, with a plot call as input. Also, the plot call should not have been evaluated (too slow!). I learned about the `substitute` command and I wrote this :

```
x = rnorm(10)
plot_call = substitute(hist(x))
function(plot_call, figurename){
    if (! figurename %in% dir("figure")) {
        png(file.path("figure", figurename))
        eval(plot_call)
        dev.off()
    } 
    knitr::include_graphics(file.path("figure", figurename))
}
```

I have two issues with this :

- it does not seem to work with multiple lines plot calls
- it seems like a dubious hack

What do you think? Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more formal way to cache code blocks is to leverage [chunk options](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html). Adding a simple `cache = TRUE` to the block header will force your plot to be re-evaluated each time block options or the code itself will change:

````
```{r expensive_plot, cache = TRUE}
# Some expensive plot
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point()
```
````

If the plot needs to be recomputed each time there's a change in the underlying data, it's possible to invalidate cache each time the file 'last edited' field changes by adding `cache.extra = file.mtime('your-csv.csv')` to your options.

Comment: Thanx, that is what I needed !